# no suitable method for read(java.lang.String)

Tags: java

Hello I'm trying to display an image I have displayed in my pictures on a Java application.
If someone could help me figure this out I would greatly appreciate it. This is the code I used when I got this error:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class JPipesCard
{
    Image img = null;

    {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read("J Pipe's Card.png");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, do consider using IDE such as Eclipse, error like this would be highlighted as you type your code -- so you can spot it without even compiling

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass a `java.util.File` as stated in [`ImageIO#read` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29):

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File("J Pipe's Card.png"));
```

Answer (score 3):

`ImageIO` does not have a `read` method that accepts a `String`. As the file is local, you need to use the one that accepts a `File` object:

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File("J Pipe's Card.png"));
```

- [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29)